# Ordering / z-indexing overlays on Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm adding 2 overlays - a [Demographics Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/demographics) and a [Fusion Tables Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables) - to a Google Map. The problem is that I need to order these layers so the Fusion Tables Layer is always on top of the Demographics Layer. It seems that whichever one I call "setMap(map)" on last is on top, but I have functionality for toggling the Demographics Layer on or off using setMap(null) and setMap(map)... but whenever it is toggled on using setMap(map), it shows up on top of the Fusion Tables Layer.

```
if (checkbox.checked) {
  demolayer.setMap(map);  //added on top
} else {
  demolayer.setMap(null);
}
```

Is there another way to order overlays besides making sure you call setMap(map) on the layer you want on top last? I've tried z-index properties with no luck. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> Is there another way to order overlays besides making sure you call setMap(map) on the layer you want on top last?

Not that I have seen.  The work around is to always remove both layers and add both back in the order you want them displayed.

You might want to "star" these enhancement requests or adding a new one (I don't see a general "allow control relative z-index of layers" enhancement request):

- http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=layer+z-index
- http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/list?can=2&q=z-index

Comment: So I tried this, adding `demolayer.setMap(null);ftlayer.setMap(null);demolayer.setMap(map);ftlayer.setMap(map);` to the last 'idle' event handler that gets called, and it didn't work - the demographics layer still shows up on top of the Fusion Tables layer. Is there a way to listen to an 'idle' or similar event for a single layer, to know when it is done being redrawn on the map? Not sure what else to do here.

Comment: There is more information available for KmlLayer than for FusionTableLayers.  But it doesn't look like any of that is available for the demographics layer.  Perhaps you could wait for the idle event after adding the bottom layer?

Comment: Yeah, I reverted to using setTimeout before calling setMap(map) on the desired top layer. Not the best way to do it, but it's a workaround for this limitation.